# How can I list what LSPs are installed, using C#?

Tags: c#-2.0, winsock, winsock-lsp

Just to clarify, I don't aim to create or install a LSP(Layered Service Provider) in C#.

Is there any way to just find a list of which ones are installed, or perhaps at least which applications have installed an LSP on a machine?

Maybe that information is stored in the registry somewhere.

Some resources I've found that describe the systems well, but seem to focus on creating the LSPs themselves in c++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513664(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.komodia.com/lsp-sub

Thanks.

Comment: There is some info in registry "hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Winsock2".